# Autolog metrics mlflow

Tags: metrics, mlflow

I have a question about autologging. I use it and I want to record another metrics.
Can I change the recorded metrics for autologging?

I found a class in the documentation `_AutologgingMetricsManager` but I don't know how can I use it.

Thanks,
Irina

Comment: can you show the snippet of code how do you use it right now?